# Added $PATH not saving in MacOS Monterey

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, mono

I'm setting up Intellisense in visual studio code for Unity, and I got an omnisharp error to add the Mono /bin to my $PATH. I used `export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/bin` and it works fine, but once I close the terminal, Intellisense does not work anymore. So I did `echo $PATH` to check if the Mono path I added is there, but it's gone. Is there a way I can add it permanently? Also, not sure if it matters or not but my shell is zsh.